# Curl + Socks5 - escape authentification data

Tags: bash, curl, socks

I'm trying to use Curl with Socks5 proxy which needs authentication:

```
curl -v -x socks5://user:password@PROXY_SERVER_IP:PROXY_PORT http://checkip.amazonaws.com
```

However, my login is email address and password contains an asterisk. I am trying to escape special characters and make it work, but nothing I tried so far worked. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by replacing @ in the login with %40

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but may useful for future readers ->

You can also use the data-urlencode flag like this :

curl -v --data-urlencode -x socks5://user:password@PROXY_SERVER_IP:PROXY_PORT http://checkip.amazonaws.com